# Creating a Shoe object

Tags: java

I cannot figure out why my code does not register that there is a max size on the object. I maybe thought it was due to the fact that the bottom variables may override the Minimum and maximum values but, it does not seem to help

```
public class Shoes {

private static final int MIN_SIZE = 1;
private static final int MAX_SIZE = 15;

private String brand;
private double price;
private int size;

public Shoes(String brand, double price, int size) {
   this.brand = brand;
   this.price = price;
   this.size = size;
}

public String getBrand() {
   return brand;
}

public void setBrand(String brand) {
   this.brand = brand;
}

public double getPrice() {
   return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
   if (price < 0) {
       System.out.println("Price Must be greater than zero!\n");
       return;
   }
   this.price = price;
}

public int getSize() {
   return size;
}

public void setSize(int size) {
   if (size > MAX_SIZE && size < MIN_SIZE) {
       System.out.println("Invalid Size!\n");

   }

}

@Override
public String toString() {
   return "Shoe [brand = " + brand + ", price = " + price + ", size = " +      size + "]";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Shoes myShoes = new Shoes("J.F.", 45.99, 10);
Shoes otherShoes = new Shoes("Addidas", 65.99, 16);

System.out.println("The shoes: ");
System.out.println(myShoes.toString());

System.out.println("Other Shoes: ");
System.out.println(otherShoes.toString());

   }
}
```

The othershoes should register as an invalid size. however it just runs the code as normal and does not output the invalid size text at all I do not understand why.

Comment: You have no size checking in the constructor, only in the `setSize()` method which you're not using. Additionally it should use `||` (or) not `&&` (and).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, in your constructor you are not using "setSize" method but you copy value from parameter directly to field "size". Because of that method "setSize" is not fired, so the validation in that method didn't happend. I suggest you modify the code of constructor, so instead of directly setting value of "size" field you would use "setSize" method like:

```
public Shoes(String brand, double price, int size) {
  this.brand = brand;
  this.price = price;
  this.setSize(size);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you're not checking the size in the constructor. You've relegated that to a separate method that is not called on object initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call the `setSize` method in your constructor. Thus, the check is not performed.

You can simply change the constructor to use the method like so:

```
public Shoes(String brand, double price, int size) {
    this.brand = brand;
    this.price = price;
    setSize(size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.
1. The data validation you have in place inside the size setter doesn't work. Your current logic says that if size is greater than 15 AND (&&) less than 1, then it will register invalid. That condition will never be true. Rather, you should say greater than 15 OR (||) less than 1.
2. You're not ever calling the size setter with the validation. You should use the setters in your constructor. So your constructor would look like this:

```
 public Shoes(String brand, double price, int size) {
   setBrand(brand);
   setPrice(price);
   setSize(size);
}
```